# How to justify, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}y^{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} (x^{n}-y^{n})$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

Let $\{a_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb C$ so that the series, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n},$  converges absolutely for all $x\in \mathbb R$ and we let $K_{1}$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb R$ and define
$f:K_{1}\subset \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ such that $$f(x):= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n}; x\in K_{1}$$

Let $x, y\in K_{1}$  with $x\neq y$; and  I wants to compute,

$f(x)- f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}y^{n};$

> **My question**: (1) Is it true that, $f(x)-f(y)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} (x^{n}-y^{n})$; if yes, how to justify it ? (2) Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} (x^{n}- y^{n})$ converges absolutely ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(u_N)_N$, $(v_N)_N$ are both convergent sequences, then also the sequence $(u_N- v_N)_N$ converges and the limit is

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} u_N - \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} v_N = \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} (u_N - v_N)$$

Now set $u_N=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n x^n$ and $v_N = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n y^n$. This justifies $(1)$.

Also $(2)$ is true. If $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ converge absolutely, then also $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n (x^n - y^n)$ does:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n (x^n - y^n)|\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty (|a_n x^n| + |a_n y^n|)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n x^n| + \sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n x^n| <\infty$$

Comment: @YAH; thanks a lot; so, under the above assumption, if I do,  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} (x^{n}- y^{n})= (x-y)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} (x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...+y^{n-1});$ then the series, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (x^{n-1}y+x^{n-2}y^{2}+...+y^{n-1})$, will also be absolutely converges; would please tell me, am I right ? or I am missing something ?; thanks;

Comment: Yes, for a similar reason: if $(u_N)_N$, $(v_N)_N$ converge to $u,v$ respectively and $v\not=0$ then also $u_N/v_N$ converges and the limit is $u/v$. Now put $u_N=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n(x^n-y^n)$ and $v_N=x-y$.

Comment: sorry I could not follow you: here in the series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} (x^{n-1}y+x^{n-2}y^{2}+...+y^{n-1});$ summand contains contains $n$- terms, namely, ($x^{n-1}y, x^{n-2}y^{2},..., y^{n-1}$); so I am bit confuse how to handle that; thanks a lot;

Comment: Thanks a lot; Then , may I get a bound for, the series, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_{n}|(|x^{n-1}y|+x^{n-2}y^{2}|+...+|y^{n-1}|)\leq  ?$; thanks;

Comment: @YAH; thanks a lot; but , $|x^{n}-y^{n}|\leq |x-y| \cdot (|x^{n-1}y|+|x^{n-2}y^{2}|+..+|y^{n-1}|)$ true for all $x, y \in \mathbb R$; and therefore, it should be reverse way; or am I missing something ?

Comment: That is correct, typo.

Comment: Thanks for every thing; so, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}||x^{n}-y^{n}| \leq |x-y| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_{n}|(|x^{n-1}|+|x^{n-2}y^{2}|+...+|y^{n-1}|) \leq ?$; (can we expect some bound for this bigger series ?);

Comment: You have a typo in your formula. Anyways, I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to show: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_{n}| (|x^{n-1}| + |x^{n-2}y|+...+|y^{n-1}|)< \infty $; is it true ?,  thanks

Comment: Yes of course, as I told you before.

Comment: By your previous argument, I agree that, $\frac{u_{N}}{v_{N}}$, converges, and so the series, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} (x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y^{2}+...+y^{n-1})$ converges; but its not clear to me that why it is absolutely converges ? Thanks ;

Comment: All your series converge absolutely.